# Getting a file path from a file handle in Windows

Tags: windows, path, filehandle

In Windows, is there a straightforward way to get the full path of a file, given only the file's handle?

I can't use GetFinalPathNameByHandle() because that's Vista+ only and our product has to work on XP.  However, something that simple, or close to it, would be best.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go: [Obtaining a File Name From a File Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366789.aspx)

Comment: Thank you.  I was aware of that technique (I guess I should have mentioned that - I apologize for the omission) and was hoping for something a little cleaner, but I guess there isn't such a thing.  At least now I know that.

However, I appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: Is there a solution for applications that are supposed to target XP as well?

Comment: Did you read the article? It shows how to do it for versions earlier than Vista, which includes XP.